# How do I append elements to a global array (in a for loop) in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an empty global array. The only simple thing I want to do is add an element to this array. It seems in swift this seemingly simple task is proving to be difficult. I am just left with an empty array and nothing is appending to my global array.

I can see that it prints out values in the for loop. So the values are actually there.

This is some stuff I have declared globally (Yes, I know global variables are bad but I will sort that out later):

```
struct HouseDetails: Decodable {
    let median_price: String
    let sale_year: String
    let transaction_count: String
    let type: String
}

var hsArray: [HouseDetails] = []
```

and in the viewDidLoad() function I have the data which I am storing in local variable "houses". When I loop through the array it prints median_price, showing that the values are there.

However when I do hsArray.append(h) it seems to do nothing.

```
let jsonUrlString = "https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/i8px-csib.json"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString)
        else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let houses = try JSONDecoder().decode([HouseDetails].self, from: data)

            for h in houses {
                hsArray.append(h)

                print(h.median_price)

            }

        }
        catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error with json serialization", jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
```

Thank you for any help. In other languages I am used to being able to append an element to the end of an existing array, so I am sure it is just a small error.

Comment: You have an asynchronous call back so the array is not updated immediately. You should probably look into adding a completion handler to the method the code above belongs to.

Comment: It is simply in the viewDidLoad() function in the ViewController.swift file. Is there a simple solution to add a completion handler? It seems awfully complicated for simply appending an element to an array.

Comment: You don’t need it to append to the array, the point is that you can call it once all the values has been added to the array so whatever code you have there you know it will not be executed until all data has been downloaded

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, why don't you simply do

```
hsArray.append(contentsOf: houses)
```

instead of all that `for loop`

```
for h in houses {
    hsArray.append(h)
    print(h.median_price)    
}
```

The issue might be the time at which you are using `hsArray`. See if the response is received after you use `hsArray`.